# Rails migration containing SQL + Active Record yields Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, environment-variables

I'm trying to run a migration that will update a row's column in my postgres database. The current column's value is an array of strings. The migration pushes two new strings into the array. The migration file contains a combination of Active Record and SQL to construct the update that will place.

Here is the code in the migration file:

```
  def up
    user = User.find_by(name: "John")
    favorite_foods = user.favorite_foods
    favorite_foods.push("apples", "grapes")
    execute (
      "UPDATE users
      SET favorite_foods = #{favorite_foods}
      WHERE id = #{user.id}"
    )
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
```

After running the migration, this is the Active Record error I get:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["`
`LINE 2: SET favorite_foods = ["orange", "mango", "banana", "cak...`

A caret appears below the first `[` that's right before the `orange` .. so it seems to be some sort of syntax issue with the array and the double quotation perhaps?

The migration fails and does not take place. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: `["orange", "mango", "banana"]` is a ruby array. If you want to use raw SQL (why would you want that I don't get), you need to convert that array into a [PostgreSQL array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html), e.g. `ARRAY['orange', 'mango', 'banana']`

Comment: Is is not possible to update an array with `User.find_by(name: 'John').update(favorite_foods: favorite_foods)`?

Comment: Yes I know I can do this using pure Active Record without any SQL `(user.update(keywords = keywords)`, but I heard/read somewhere that using raw SQL for these kinds of updates in the migration file is best. 

But if that's not looked down upon then I suppose I'm down for Active Record.

Comment: what about this `SET favorite_foods = ARRAY#{favorite_foods}` ? did you try it ?